# JOLT to divide number inside array

Tags: json, jolt

I have JSON:

```
{
  "queryParams": {
    "limit": [
      "500"
    ],
    "breakdowns": [
      "impression_device,publisher_platform,platform_position"
    ]
  },
  "body": ""
}
```

I want to dynamically divide number inside `limit` array by 2.

I tried with:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "queryParams": {
        "limit": "=divide(@(2,limit), 2)"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

But it didnt change anything. How to fix it?

Expected:

```
{
  "queryParams": {
    "limit": [
      "250"
    ],
    "breakdowns": [
      "impression_device,publisher_platform,platform_position"
    ]
  },
  "body": ""
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need two step conversion, since `limit` is not an integer or a single value but an array, and need to extract the desired value from that array by using some functions such as `firstElement`, `intSum` .. etc. in the first step, and then apply `divide` within **modify-overwrite-beta** transformation. If you want to hide the auxiliary key(`lmt`), then apply **shift** transformation consecutively.

So, consider using the *specification* below

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "queryParams": {
        "lmt": "=firstElement(@(1,limit))",
        "limit": "=divide(@(1,lmt),2)"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "queryParams": {
        "limit": "&1.limit",
        "breakdowns": "&1.breakdowns"        
      },
      "body": "body"
    }
  }
]
```